# How to display status on home page in laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to display user's status on the homepage. This is my code:

```
return view('timeline.index');
$Statuses = Status::where(function($query){
        return $query->where('user_id', Auth::user('id')->list('id'));
})->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();

dd($Statuses);
```

As soon as I refresh my home page it should display some data in array type order.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that before your `dd()` you have a `return` statement. The method stops right there.

Comment your `return view('timeline.index');` and you will be able to reach `$Statuses` initialization and dumping.

More about [return](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.return.php).

If you want to pass `$Statuses` to the view do the following:

```
$Statuses = Status::where(function($query){
        return $query->where('user_id', Auth::user('id')->list('id'));
})->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();

return view('timeline.index')->withStatuses($Statuses);
```

And in your view you can access it as @Alexey mentioned in his comment.

Also you can just use `Auth::user()->id`.